# Import data from CSV files from ftp folder into SQL server

Tags: import, ssis-2012

We need to import data from from CSV files from ftp folder containing many sub folders and every sub folder represents one data location means locationId into SQL server. After every One hour there are new CSV file at ftp. So my Job is to read this data automatically.

Comment: What do you already know about reading a CSV into SQLServer (OPENROWSET/BULK INSERT/External applications) ? As it stands, this question is a bit broad - almost like you want us to do your entire job for you..

Comment: I know how we can use SSIS to read from FTP and insert into SQL server but as new files will arrive there I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: So you're not even using ftp to deliver these files onto the sql server where a timed job could read them? Youre looking for a system where some code will collect files off an FTP server after being notified that they've arrived, and then upload them to SQLS? This question is getting broader...